# What are the benefits of including a return statement in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made up a simple CAPTCHA using JQuery. And while it works fine, I don't think I'm doing it the right way.

When the page loads, the function is called:

```
getAnswer(answer);
```

Which is:

```
function getAnswer() {  
    var min = 0;
    var max = 50;
    var ranNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    var ranNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    $('#ran1').html(ranNum1).show();
    $('#plus').html("+").show();
    $('#ran2').html(ranNum2).show();
    answer = ranNum1 + ranNum2;
}
```

And when I compare `answer` to the user's input:

```
if(answer != captcha) {
    $('#captchaErr').html("CAPTCHA is Incorrect").show().delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    $('#captcha').focus();
    return false;
}
```

it works. But in looking at a lot of Q&A regarding this here on SO, it seems like I should include a `return` statement in the function, which also works.

Since it works both ways, what are the benefits and drawbacks of including the `return` statement?

Comment: A captcha that's client-side (i.e. in JavaScript only) is completely useless.

Comment: @ceejayoz - that doesn't address my question.

Comment: This is for my benefit, my practice. I'm new to JQuery. I do have my own CAPTCHA that I made using PHP.

Comment: `getAnswer(answer);` no need to pass `arguments` on the function since it doesn't have any `parameters`.  it'll all depends on your need.  If your using it as a `getter` then a return value will be better.

Comment: @roullie - thank you. I'm learning as I go and just want to make sure I get things right the first time around.

Comment: If your function name is called "getXXX", you definitely should return the answer, and don't make your `answer` a global variable. (that's why it works without return atm)

Comment: Your question my be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as you're asking for critique on working code.

Comment: @DJDavid98 - I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to return any value.

First of all, rename your function to `showQuestion` or something; as name suggest, it only shows question and it's not getter. `answer` variable should be stored somewhere - not recommended is global variable, but you can pack *ran1*, *plus* and *ran2* into one DIV, and set data field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  showQuestion();
}
```

Last line in `showQuestion`:

```
$('#question').data('answer', answer);
```

OR you can leave function name like `getQuestion()`, return correct answer and set it in `ready()` function.

When you want to validate, simply get answer:

```
var answer = $('#question').data('answer');
```

Note that's local variable, not global.

*Of course you know that captcha can't be client-side?*

Comment: I do know that. I'm learning JQuery and simply chose this as an exercise. I wrote the same CAPTCHA using PHP. That's what I use. This is just for learning purposes. I'm amazed at the power of JQuery. This is a vast world that's a whole lot of fun. And I appreciate your response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid using `Global Variable`. As a a global variable, you maybe change it often, and difficult to debug with global variable.
Try to understand `closure` in `Js` is also helpful.:)

Comment: piglovesx - I'll do that. Thanks.